# dupTo oddities pertaining to STDOUT

Tags: haskell, operating-system, daemon, ghc, stdio

I'm writing some code to daemonize a process. Naturally, I want to be able to redirect the STDOUT.

However, once I switch file descriptors around, Haskell's functions for printing don't write anything to my file nor to the console, but calling `fdWrite` on the newly updated `stdOutput` file descriptor works as intended.

As a side note, If I use any of Haskell's printing functions (print, hPutStr, etc) before I `daemonize'`, everything works as intended (stdout gets written to my file)

How do I fix this issue?

Here is how I'm daemonizing:

```
daemonize' :: Maybe String -> Maybe String -> IO () -> IO () 
daemonize' outpath errpath program = do
  forkProcess $ do
    createSession
    forkProcess $ do
      redirectIO outpath errpath
      blockSignal sigHUP
      program
    exitImmediately ExitSuccess
  exitImmediately ExitSuccess

blockSignal :: Signal -> IO () 
blockSignal sig = installHandler sig Ignore Nothing >> (return ())
```

This is the code that redirects STDOUT:

```
redirectIO :: Maybe String -> Maybe String -> IO ()
redirectIO outpath errpath = do
  dnull <- openFd "/dev/null" ReadWrite Nothing defaultFileFlags
  closeFd stdInput >> dupTo dnull stdInput
  case outpath of
    Nothing -> closeFd stdOutput >> dupTo dnull stdOutput >> return ()
    Just out -> do
      fdWrite stdOutput "HELLO"
      fd <- openFd out ReadWrite Nothing defaultFileFlags
      setFdOption fd AppendOnWrite True
      dupTo fd stdOutput
      closeFd fd
  case errpath of
    Nothing -> closeFd stdError >> dupTo dnull stdError >> return ()
    Just err -> do
      fd <- openFd err ReadWrite Nothing defaultFileFlags
      setFdOption fd AppendOnWrite True
      dupTo fd stdError
      closeFd fd
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at `strace` to see if something obvious is wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure we're not missing something, but what OS are you using?

Comment: This example http://lpaste.net/137599 works for me on OSX. I see "HELLO" on the console and I get 1, 2, etc. in the file `output`. Note that `output` and `error` have to first exist.

Comment: I'm using OS X. It must be something else, as this is a part of a huge piece of software.

Comment: I ran OS X's dtrace, and I get the same log whether or not I flush stdout. Then, in my program, I commented out a call to `scottyT` and suddenly it worked. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't solved my problem, these issues with `stdout` not redirecting properly only appear when my program is daemonized as above; redirecting `stdout` while the program is not daemonized works as expected, writing to a file I specify.

UPDATE 7.31.15:

It turns out that the stdout handle wasn't buffering properly. After I made the `stdout` and `stderr` `Handle`s stop buffering, everything worked as intended.

```
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
hSetBuffering stderr NoBuffering -- for consistency
hSetBuffering stdin  NoBuffering -- for consistency
```